# How can I arrange the items of the menu?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this example:

https://jsfiddle.net/y3gfd0cv/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="hhh">
<div class="patrat1 inline">
    <p class="menu1"><img class="sageata" src="http://paul.dac-proiect.ro/wp-content/themes/wpbootstrap/images/logo-arrow.png">MENU1</p>
    <p class="menu2"><img class="sageata" src="http://paul.dac-proiect.ro/wp-content/themes/wpbootstrap/images/logo-arrow.png">MENU2</p> 

</div>
```

**JS:**

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $('.patrat2 .content2').hide();
     $('.patrat1 p img').hide();
     $('.patrat1 p:first-child img').show();

      $('.patrat1').on('click', 'p', function () {   //aici this=p
        $('.patrat1 img').hide();
        $(this).find('img').show();
    });


});
```

I put a picture to understand better what i want to do:

[image]

Basically I want to align menu items remain in that position no matter if or not the selected item.I tried to add `padding-left:X value` but not good.

I must change the HTML code?
Could you help me with any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can be done with some CSS rules:

```
p{
    margin-left: 20px;
    position: relative;
}

p img{
    position: absolute;
    left: -20px;
}
```

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/y3gfd0cv/2/

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to create some custom class and change `visibility` instead of `display` property as jQuery does in `show` and `hide` methods.

Then you can use `addClass` and `removeClass` methods instead:

https://jsfiddle.net/y3gfd0cv/1/

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.patrat2 .content2').hide();
  $('.patrat1 p img').addClass( 'hidden' );
  $('.patrat1 p:first-child img').removeClass( 'hidden' );

  $('.patrat1').on('click', 'p', function () {   //aici this=p
    $('.patrat1 img').addClass( 'hidden' );
    $(this).find('img').removeClass( 'hidden' );
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hhh">
<div class="patrat1 inline">
    <p class="menu1"><img class="sageata" src="http://paul.dac-proiect.ro/wp-content/themes/wpbootstrap/images/logo-arrow.png">MENU1</p>
    <p class="menu2"><img class="sageata" src="http://paul.dac-proiect.ro/wp-content/themes/wpbootstrap/images/logo-arrow.png">MENU2</p>
</div>
```